# Why is my variables template loaded, but not in steps template? (shown in images)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

Can someone tell me why my variables template is loaded in 1 (image), one of the variables shown in 2 (image), but not useable in my template anymore?

I tried following MS docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#job-stage-and-step-templates-with-parameters

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I noticed that it did load the env:variables in PS.

Eventually changing the variable names including: `${{ variables.XXXX }}` to `$(XXXX)` resolved my issue mentioned above.